# Why am I earning more nikefuel than other people?

Tags: running

I'm using Nike+SportBand (a pedometer) and I got about 262 nikeFuel per kilometer.
My friend has Nike+Running App (tracking using GPS) in his android phone and he gets 207 nikefuel per kilometer.

He has different weight (I'm by 20% heavier) and he's running faster (by 20%).
I have tried today to set different weight and run faster and I got the same nikefuel points as before.

What makes the difference? (I'm just curious and confused).

Comment: I couldn't find anything online about a Nike device called "[SportBar](https://www.google.com/search?q=nike+sportbar)".  Does it have another name?

Comment: yep. you were right. it is sportband.

Comment: (Thanks for migration. I thought that it is wrong place for the question, but I couldn't hound any better place.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s off topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, I don't use any Nike products and can therefore not verify my answer myself.
All information is taken from the Nike+ Support page, though, so I'm pretty confident it's correct.

The most likely reason for your differing nikefuel gains is the device type. If you are using the SportsBand and your friend is using the RunningApp, your nikefuel is most likely calculated differently, as each device is optimized to track a certain type of activity.
As per [the specific support page:](https://support-en-us.nikeplus.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/38261/p/3169,3178/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xMzk3NjcyNDUxL3NpZC9ya1IxYllSbA==)

> If you use multiple Nike+ devices, you may receive a different
>   NikeFuel amounts on each device for the same workout. That's because
>   each Nike+ device uses different technologies and are optimized for
>   different experiences.
>
> For example, the SportWatch GPS is optimized for pace and distance and
>   is the best device for measuring those metrics if you are a runner or
>   walker, while the Nike+ FuelBand or FuelBand SE is optimized to
>   capture your everyday activity as NikeFuel and is the best option for
>   measuring your overall athletic life.
>
> Feel free to wear both devices at once if you're interested in both
>   your sport-specific workout data and your overall activity data. Some
>   variation between the two is to be expected and shouldn't be cause for
>   concern.

(If my citation is violating any kind of copyright please edit it and/or let me know.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with NikeFuel is that it isn't truly a direct measure of your activity.  In other words, it's an approximation based on oxygen use as [per Mashable](http://mashable.com/2013/01/31/nike-fuelband/):

> "The partnerships with Arizona State and other partners were critical in developing the foundation for NikeFuel. Oxygen kinetics is the most universal way to understand the level of exertion to perform a core movement," says Ricky Engelberg, Experience Director of Digital Sport at Nike.

[Per Nike Support](https://support-en-us.nikeplus.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/38261/p/3169,3178/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xMzk3NjcyNDUxL3NpZC9ya1IxYllSbA==), the algorithm for NikeFuel points is different based on the device used:

> If you use multiple Nike+ devices, you may receive a different NikeFuel amounts on each device for the same workout. That's because each Nike+ device uses different technologies and are optimized for different experiences.

And things can be very inconsistent when you use the Nike FuelBand as [per the NY Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/07/29/technology/nike-fuelband-tracks-physical-activity-inconsistently.html?_r=1&):

> One lazy Sunday, I lounged around my apartment with my iPad and an endless pot of coffee, barely moving. But the band delivered a cheery message: I’d hit my goal for the day. Huh?

The problem in that case is that there is nothing that helps you change and correct for the better in any consistent manner.  Some people have gotten more points from eating pizza than climbing stairs.